# jQuery DataTable issue with angular $resource.query() reply object in DataTables v1.10.2 and v1.10.4

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables

Changes in a function fnAddData() in DataTable (to the following code) has introduced issues with angularJS $resource.query():

```
    this.fnAddData = function( data, redraw )
    {
        var api = this.api( true );

        /* Check if we want to add multiple rows or not */
        var rows = $.isArray(data) && ( $.isArray(data[0]) || $.isPlainObject(data[0]) ) ?
            api.rows.add( data ) :
            api.row.add( data );

        if ( redraw === undefined || redraw ) {
            api.draw();
        }

        return rows.flatten().toArray();
    };
```

The return object from $resource.query is an array of $resource objects. The check for whether to add the passed object as multiple rows or not fails because $.isPlainObject returns false. The following error is displayed:

*DataTables warning: table id=DataTable_Table_1 - Requested unknown parameter 'xyz...' for row 0. For more information about this error please see http://datables.net/tn/4.*

Has anyone found a work-around for this, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up logging the bug in their website and using these hacks as a fix for now:

1. Either: using a container object to hold that array
2. Or: using JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() before passing the $resource object to dataTables: -

   ```
   var objectToSendToDataTables = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
   ```